Terraform and Databricks API does not recognize that it just created a new workspace, and requires setting a host property
I am getting this warning that never stops repeating (it goes on for 15 minutes+ before I am forced to cancel my CI/CD github actions pipeline):
024-07-13T14:05:37.152Z [INFO]  Starting apply for module.first_workspace.databricks_mws_workspaces.this
module.first_workspace.databricks_mws_workspaces.this: Creating...
2024-07-13T14:05:43.489Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Workspace xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx is PROVISIONING: Workspace resources are being set up.: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:43.489Z
2024-07-13T14:05:44.260Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Workspace xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx is PROVISIONING: Workspace resources are being set up.: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:44.260Z
2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Workspace is now running: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:45.534Z
2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Creating client for host https://xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx.cloud.databricks.com based on host=https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com, username=email@example.com, *** account_id=xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z
2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Using directly configured basic authentication: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z
2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: Configured basic auth: host=https://xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx.cloud.databricks.com, username=email@example.com, *** timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:45.535Z
2024-07-13T14:05:45.657Z [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.6.5: /api/2.0/token/list:403 - Databricks API (/api/2.0/token/list) requires you to set `host` property (or DATABRICKS_HOST env variable) to result of `databricks_mws_workspaces.this.workspace_url`. This error may happen if you're using provider in both normal and multiworkspace mode. Please refactor your code into different modules. Runnable example that we use for integration testing can be found in this repository at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/token.html#list: timestamp=2024-07-13T14:05:45.657Z
module.first_workspace.databricks_mws_workspaces.this: Still creating...

I have already looked at this related post: Error: Databricks API requires you to set `host` property but the answer doesn't seem to solve my problem.
My goal is simple: I want to create a workspace. After I create the workspace, I plan to assign it to a pre-existing metastore/unity catalog. However, my terraform code issues warnings immediately after creating my workspace. I see that it exists in the UI, but terraform doesn't recognize that it was just created. I receive an infinite loop of warnings instead to provide the host.
The error, and the documentation say that I need to reference workspace-level resources in a separate module from mws-level resources,  but I haven't even tried spinning up workspace-level resources so far as I can see. I am wondering if error is occurring because the workspace has not been assigned to a metastore yet, but maybe that is off-base.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my file structure:
│
└───terraform
    │
    ├───dev
    │       main.tf
    │       terraform.tfvars
    │       variables.tf
    │
    ├───modules
    │   │
    │   └───workspace
    │           data.tf
    │           iam.tf
    │           main.tf
    │           outputs.tf
    │           s3.tf
    │           variables.tf
    │           vpc.tf
    │           vpc_endpoints.tf
    │           workspace.tf

root module:
dev/main.tf
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = <backend-bucket>
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = <locktable>
    encrypt        = true
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "~>1.6.5"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      tag1 = "tag1"
      tag2 = "tag2"
      tag3 = "tag3"
      tag4 = "tag4"
    }
  }
}

provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "mws"
  host       = "https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com"
  account_id = <databricks_account_id>
  username   = <databricks_username>
  password   = <databricks_password>
}

module "first_workspace" {
  source = "../modules/workspace"
  databricks_account_id = <databricks_account_id>
  username = <databricks_username>
  password = <databricks_password>
  region = "us-east-1"
  prefix = "coolprefix"
  this_repository = var.this_repository
  current_environment = var.current_environment
  providers = {
    databricks.mws = databricks.mws
  }
}

dev/terraform.tfvars:
current_environment = "dev"
aws_account_number = <aws_account_number>
this_repository = "databricks"

dev/variables.tf:
variable "aws_account_number" {
    description = "AWS Account Number for the given environment"
    type        = string
    default     = ""
}

variable current_environment {
    description = "The deployment current_environment"
    type = string
    default = ""
}

variable "this_repository" {
  description = "this repository name"
  type = string
  default = ""
}

Workspace module:
modules/workspace/data.tf:
data "databricks_aws_assume_role_policy" "this" {
  external_id = var.databricks_account_id
  provider = databricks.mws
}

data "databricks_aws_crossaccount_policy" "this" {
  provider    = databricks.mws
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

data "databricks_aws_bucket_policy" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.bucket
}

modules/workspace/iam.tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "cross_account_role" {
  name               = "${local.prefix}-crossaccount"
  assume_role_policy = data.databricks_aws_assume_role_policy.this.json
  tags               = var.tags
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "this" {
  name   = "${local.prefix}-policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.id
  policy = data.databricks_aws_crossaccount_policy.this.json
}

modules/workspace/main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "~>1.6.5"
      configuration_aliases = [ databricks.mws ]
    }

    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~>5.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "random_string" "naming" {
  special = false
  upper   = false
  length  = 6
}

modules/workspace/outputs.tf
output "databricks_host" {
  value = databricks_mws_workspaces.this.workspace_url
}

output "databricks_token" {
  value     = databricks_mws_workspaces.this.token[0].token_value
  sensitive = true
}

output "workspace_id" {
  value = databricks_mws_workspaces.this.workspace_id
}

modules/workspace/s3.tf
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "root_storage_bucket" {
  bucket        = "${var.prefix}-${var.this_repository}-rootbucket-${var.current_environment}"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "root_storage_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.bucket

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Disabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "root_storage_bucket" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "root_bucket_policy" {
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  policy     = data.databricks_aws_bucket_policy.this.json
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.root_storage_bucket]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "state" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "root_storage_bucket" {
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  acl        = "private"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.state]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning_example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Disabled"
  }
}

modules/workspace/variables.tf
variable "databricks_account_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Databricks Account ID"
}

variable "databricks_client_id" {
  type = string
  default = ""
  sensitive = true
}
variable "databricks_client_secret" {
  type = string
  default = ""
  sensitive = true
}

variable "username" {
  type = string
  default = ""
}

variable "password" {
  type = string
  default = ""
  sensitive = true
}

variable "current_environment" {
  type = string
  default = ""
}

variable "this_repository" {
  type = string
}

variable "region" {
  default     = "us-east-2"
  type        = string
  description = "AWS region to deploy to"
}

variable "prefix" {
  default     = "demo"
  type        = string
  description = "Prefix for use in the generated names"
}

variable "tags" {
  default     = {}
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Optional tags to add to created resources"
}

variable "cidr_block" {
  description = "IP range for AWS VPC"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.4.0.0/16"
}


locals {
  prefix                       = "${var.prefix}-${var.this_repository}-${var.current_environment}-${random_string.naming.result}"
  workspace_name               = "${var.prefix}-${var.current_environment}"
}

modules/workspace/vpc_endpoints.tf
module "vpc_endpoints" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws//modules/vpc-endpoints"
  version = "5.7.0"

  vpc_id             = module.vpc.vpc_id
  security_group_ids = [module.vpc.default_security_group_id]

  endpoints = {
    s3 = {
      service      = "s3"
      service_type = "Gateway"
      route_table_ids = flatten([
        module.vpc.private_route_table_ids,
      module.vpc.public_route_table_ids])
      tags = {
        Name = "${local.prefix}-s3-vpc-endpoint"
      }
    },
    sts = {
      service             = "sts"
      private_dns_enabled = true
      subnet_ids          = module.vpc.private_subnets
      tags = {
        Name = "${local.prefix}-sts-vpc-endpoint"
      }
    },
    kinesis-streams = {
      service             = "kinesis-streams"
      private_dns_enabled = true
      subnet_ids          = module.vpc.private_subnets
      tags = {
        Name = "${local.prefix}-kinesis-vpc-endpoint"
      }
    },
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

modules/workspace/workspace.tf
resource "databricks_mws_networks" "this" {
  account_id         = var.databricks_account_id
  network_name       = "${local.prefix}-network"
  security_group_ids = [module.vpc.default_security_group_id]
  subnet_ids         = module.vpc.private_subnets
  vpc_id             = module.vpc.vpc_id
  provider = databricks.mws
}

resource "databricks_mws_storage_configurations" "this" {
  account_id                 = var.databricks_account_id
  bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.root_storage_bucket.bucket
  storage_configuration_name = "${local.prefix}-storage"
  provider = databricks.mws
}

resource "databricks_mws_credentials" "this" {
  account_id       = var.databricks_account_id
  role_arn         = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.arn
  credentials_name = "${local.prefix}-creds"
  depends_on       = [time_sleep.wait, aws_iam_role_policy.this]
  provider = databricks.mws
}

## Adding 20 second timer to avoid Failed credential validation check
resource "time_sleep" "wait" {
  create_duration = "20s"
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy.this
  ]
}

resource "databricks_mws_workspaces" "this" {
  account_id     = var.databricks_account_id
  aws_region     = var.region
  workspace_name = local.workspace_name
  provider = databricks.mws

  credentials_id           = databricks_mws_credentials.this.credentials_id
  storage_configuration_id = databricks_mws_storage_configurations.this.storage_configuration_id
  network_id               = databricks_mws_networks.this.network_id

  token {
    comment = "Terraform"
  }
}

